# XSL: Setting XML attribute in root element depending on multiple variables in original document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML as follows (simplified for ease of answering):

```
<root>
  <element att1="yes" att2="no" other attributes... />
  <element att1="yes" att2="no" other attributes... />
  <element att1="no" att2="yes" other attributes... />
  <element att1="yes" att2="no" other attributes... />
  <element att1="yes" att2="yes" other attributes... />
</root>
```

I have an XSL that will check if att1 and att2 are both "yes" and if so, put them in the transformed XML (with a similar format).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/element">
      <xsl:variable name="att1" select="@att1"/>
      <xsl:variable name="att2" select="@att2"/>
      <xsl:if test="$att1 == 'yes'">
       <xsl:if test="$att2 == 'yes'">
         <!-- print new element with attributes -->
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I am trying to do is, since if both att1 and att2 are "no", nothing will get returned except:

```
<root>
</root>
```

In such a case, I want to stamp an attribute on the root element, something like BlankXML="Y", as follows:

```
<root BlankXML="Y">
</root>
```

So basically, if every element's att1 and att2 are "no", pass this BlankXML attribute on the root element.

This is where I am stuck. In a full programming language I would probably create a counter variable and increment it every time I get to the part where I print the new XML and at the end, if the counter is still 0, add the BlankXML element. However in XSL, I'm not sure exactly how to do this. From what I understand, variables are more like constants and can't be incremented like this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking at it from the wrong angle. The right point-of-view is from above. Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="output" select="root/element[@att1='yes' and @att2='yes']" />
    <root>
        <xsl:if test="not(count($output))">
            <xsl:attribute name="blank">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$output"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. I'm still new to XSL and it's not quite the same coming from a "full" programming language.